# JavaCV/OpevCV Images classification and training

Tags: java, opencv, javacv, haar-classifier

I'm trying to create a program that will train some negative images and also positive images (with opencv).

The final result that i'm trying to reach is to make an input of an image file (source file) and generate a "grade" that tells how "good" the image is (in comparison to the other negative images) or either the image is "good" or "bad".

I searched widely in the net but didn't find my answers.

Hope you can help me with this.
Thanks!

Comment: Try to be more specific on your question, since it seems like your question is quite broad.

Comment: hmm, careful. afaik, javacv, being based on opencv's deprecated c-api can't read cascadefiles done by the current tools, and the older tools are no more available now. please use opencv's own java api then, not javacv.